# Get Doctrine to act on an annotation change

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have been using annotations in a Symfony application to define ORM mappings with Doctrine.

I want to change an existing, string-holding property called "author" so that it now instead acts as a reference to a User entity. I change the  annotations above my property's definition from this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
 */
```

... to this:

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

Now the problem: When I run `doctrine:migrations:diff` in order to generate a migration, I get a message saying "No changes detected in your mapping information."

Similarly, when I run `doctrine:schema:update`, I get a message saying that there is "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata."

===

Update: After dropping the database and re-running an installation, I now get the following error message when running `doctrine:migrations:diff`:

[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Column name `id` referenced for relation from AppBundle\Entity\Post towards FOS\UserBundle\Model\User does not exist.

This comes even as `DESC users` returns the following:

```
mysql> DESC users;
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username              | varchar(180)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
```

... so I'm a bit farther than where I originally was, but my basic question still applies: **What information or action is still needed in order to get Doctrine to happily build a ManyToOne mapping on this column?**

===

Additional edit: Thanks to the answer from goto, I peeked around and saw that our application already had an entity extending the FOS UserBundle entity. So I changed my annotations to be as follows:

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

... and everything worked.

Comment: Thanks. I have now added the original annotations.

Comment: Can you check your database table? does it have the `user_id`column? it seems to me you already did the changes in database so doctrine doens't see any changes.

Comment: That's a good thing to check for. It does not exist in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create your own entity as describe in the FOS user doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-3-create-your-user-class

Then you'll have to map it to your entity

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"all"})
```